# Magento Event Model question

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm pretty newbie on the Magento stuff and right now I'm lock in one thing. I've been trying to understand the Magento's event model and I found this line:

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('payment_method_is_active', array(
        'result'          => $checkResult,
        'method_instance' => $this,
        'quote'           => $quote,
    ));
```

Now, I understand that the dispatchEvent calls the event with the name "payment_method_is_active", the problem is I can't find this event nowhere. I thought it should be in Mage->Payment->Model->Method-> , but I can't find it until now.

Could you help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the code you've put isn't *calling* the event but *dispatching* it, so that other module can *listen* to it.
In this case, this event is listened by the Sales module: you can check that by opening the app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml, inside the tag `<events>` (inside `<adminhtml>`), you'll see:

```
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <sales_billing_agreement>
                    <class>sales/observer</class>
                    <method>restrictAdminBillingAgreementUsage</method>
                </sales_billing_agreement>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
```

You can see that the first tag matches the name of the event (`payment_method_is_active`).
`sales_billing_agreement` is just a name to identify the observation.
`<class>sales/observer</class>` tells you that the file which contains the method is `Mage_Sales_Model_Observer`.
And `<method>restrictAdminBillingAgreementUsage</method>` is the name of the method in this file that take some action when the event is dispatched and work with.
Having a look at this method, you'll see that it takes one parameter, `$observer` and that throufh that `$observer` you can access to the data set in the event, ie: to access `'result'` -> `$methodInstance = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();`

Hope That Helps

Answer (score 1):

You will not find any class or method that represents this event. You can define in your modules config.xml that you want to observe this event and what method should be called whenever this event is fired. For more information about Magento Event Observer e.g. look at http://codemagento.com/2011/04/observers-and-dispatching-events/.

Comment: Thanks Simon for your anwer, the problem is that I've implemented a payment method and hacking the code I've been going down to this piece of code that doesn't allow my payment method to be seen by checkout page. BUT I've say in the options "Yes" to be seen by the customer as payment method. To be honest I'm a little bit annoyed for this.

Please if you can give me a hand on this, is really urgent and I don't find answers no matter I look for.

Regards,

Melvin

Comment: You can download some exmaple code here: [http://examples.oreilly.de/german_examples/magentopaiger/](http://examples.oreilly.de/german_examples/magentopaiger/). The module Webkochshop_Payment is a simple payment module. Hope this helps. You can also find other tutorials on the web. E.g. [here](https://colourgray.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/magento-create-a-custom-payment-method/) or [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/).